# How to select data from multiple tables with limit 1 for one table

Tags: mysql

I have multiple checkboxes where user can add education data to database. My structure looks following in database: I have three tables, user_education where I keep the record users selected education levels (it can have multiple rows for the same `user_id`), education, where I store user education description (only one row per `user_id`), and education levels where I store all the degrees.

### user_education

```
id | user_id | education_id
1    83        1
2    83        2
```

### education_description

```
user_id | description
83        test
```

### education_levels

```
education_id | education
1              alusharidus
2              keskharidus
3              Bachelor’s degree
4              Master’s degree
```

and so on. My question is how can I select all the data for the specific user, but only show the description once?

I tried running this:

```
select
    user_education.education_id,
    education_levels.education,
    education_description.description
from
    user_education
        join education_description
        left join education_levels
            on user_education.education_id=education_levels.education_id and education_description.user_id = user_education.user_id WHERE user_education.user_id=83;
```

which gave me this:

[image]

and here is the description inserted multiple times, but I would like to only have it once. Is my structure wrong for this type of logic? If not, how can I select it only once, so I can append the data for the user after he submits the form?

### EDIT

adding desired result

### education_description

```
user_id | education | description
83        test        testing
83        test2
83        test3
```

Comment: Use GROUP BY education_description.user_id

Comment: So it will display record for each description only once.

Comment: @HarshSanghani this gives me only 1 row, even though there are multiple records for specific user.

Comment: You have multiple rows as description for 1 user?

Comment: So you need only one education for the user with all other detail of user?

Comment: can you please show me your current desired result?

Comment: @HarshSanghani I need only once description, but all the other data. So all education_id's, educations, but only one description

Comment: ok ok got your issue

Comment: GROUP BY user_education.user_id Can you please try this?

Comment: @HarshSanghani kindly check the edit

Comment: @HarshSanghani the same. displays only one row.

Comment: Yes it is because there is only one user

Comment: if you need all education there then wait for moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this answer :-

```
select
    user_education.education_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(education_levels.education separator ' ,'),
    education_description.description
from
    user_education
        join education_description
        left join education_levels
            on user_education.education_id=education_levels.education_id and education_description.user_id = user_education.user_id 
WHERE user_education.user_id=83 
GROUP BY user_education.user_id;
```

Comment: can you please try this answer?

Comment: It will display one record for user id 83 and education will be comma.

Comment: can you tell me output for this answer?

Comment: Just tried it and it separates the values with coma. Is my structure bad or not? Becuase can I now set chechbox selected based on the group concat?

Comment: your structure is not bad, For the selection of checkbox you have to take id I think.

Comment: If this answer is helpful to you then please make correct and up vote the answer :)